# 1 Material 1 Texture from Blender to Unity

Tags: transparency, unity

So i have a model that has Transparent Eyelashes. I created an Atlas for all textures(Body,eyelashes, eyes etc) So Atlas image is png Transparent. The principle i use is 1 Material 1 Texture for every model but when i export it as .fbx and import it in Unity eyelashes look weird. Rendering mode is Opaque but if i change it to Transparent it looks like this Any help please? I’ve been struggling with this issue for days. In blender it looks fine when i connect the Alpha from Image Texture to Alpha in Principled BSDF. Even using Alpha Clipping still makes it look weird. If i use One material for Eyelashes and change it to transparent then it works fine BUT we don’t want to use more then 1 material. Is there a way?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: One note. The Eyelashes texture by itself isn't transparent.